# Connect to PostgreSQL from libreoffice base with SDBC

Tags: postgresql, connection, libreoffice

I'm trying to open a connection to a PostgreSQL database from LibreOffice with SDBC. After installing the "postrgre-sdbc-0.7.6" plugin, the "postgresql" datasource appears.
The system asks for the datasource URL where I enter my IP

```
192.168.0.12
```

then my user name, ticks the "Password required" box, and after entering my password the "Test connection" button gives me the following error message.

```
A driver is not registered for the URL sdbc:postresql:192.168.0.12
```

I tried adding the port to the URL (192.168.0.12:5432), same error.
As suggested I also rebooted both base and the computer, no luck either.

I know the server is running correctly as I access it no problem from pgAdminIII with these parameters.

As suggested by Richard, I also tried

```
host=192.168.0.12 port=5432 dbname=dataerp connect_timeout=10
host=192.168.0.12 port=5432 dbname=dataerp 
host=192.168.0.12 dbname=dataerp
dbname=dataerp host=192.168.0.12
```

also

```
//192.168.0.12/dataerp
//192.168.0.12:5432/dataerp
192.168.0.12:5432:dataerp
192.168.0.12:5432:dataerp:myusername:mypassword
192.168.0.12:5432=dataerp
```

Nothing works, I still get the same error message
Any help welcome!

---

After investigations, I had installed the postgresql ODBC driver doing

```
sudo apt-get install odbc-postgresql
```

While what was needed was:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql
```

The correct connection syntax was

```
host=192.168.0.12 port=5432 dbname=dataerp
```

Do not forget to reboot after this or it won't work!
This tip was found [here](http://adventurer.org.nz/?page=computing/narratives/2012-11-13_LibreOffice-Postgresql.txt)

Comment: By reboot - I take it you mean restart Libreoffice, rather than the machine itself. That shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want a raw IP address, you want a libpq connection string.

A quick google for "sdbc postgresql url" would give you the [sdbc driver page](http://www.openoffice.org/dba/drivers/postgresql/) which gives an example, and a link to the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html).

In short you want a string something like

```
dbname=mydatabase host=192.168.0.12 or postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
```

There are other options for port etc too - see the docs above in the "Connection Strings" section.

Comment: Hi, As suggested I just tried to enter a connection string as described in the various documents.

Comment: After investigations, I had installed the postgresql ODBC driver doing

    sudo apt-get install odbc-postgresql
While what was needed was:

    sudo apt-get install libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql
Do not forget to reboot after this or it won't work!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to download jdbc jar file postgresql and do the following,
Add the JAR file containing the PostGreSQL driver to OOo's CLASSPATH. This is what I do to add new JDBC drivers to OOo's CLASSPATH: In OOo call "Tools" > "Options" > "OpenOffice.org" > "Java" > press "Class Path..." > press "Add Archive..." > locate and select the archive. Now go for the new db connection by selecting jdbc. thats all